# FFMPEG getting crop data on 2-3 segments

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i "+file+" -ss 10 -t 20 -vf cropdetect -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/crop/ { print  $NF }' | tail -1
```

I take a crop from 10 to 20 seconds. At the moment, I came across a video in which the screen is dark from 10 to 20 seconds. Accordingly, the crop data is incorrect.

Remove the time and check the whole thing from start to finish, too much time is running out. How is it possible to check not just one segment, but say 3 seconds 10-20/200-210/3000-3010. If we give out a crop on all three segments, if not, we give the original ones.

Actually, how to implement it and is there a more reliable version?

At the moment, the video is running for 4 hours, launched to get a crop. I wait for at least 20 seconds, not an exit as I understand...

Comment: try framestep: `-vf framestep=150,cropdetect`

Comment: I reached framestep=10000, in all cases I waited more than 5 minutes. Perhaps there is another way to get a crop? I understand ffmpeg iterates over each frame and counts it. And so, to take 1000 2000 3000 10000 frames and perform a crop on them? Using ffprobe, it is possible to get the number of frames or the number of frames per second, but the best option is 1

Comment: Maybe use select scene `-vf select='gt(scene\,0.4)',cropdetect -frames:v 5`

Comment: Cgt (scene\,0.4) works much faster with a video duration of 200 minutes. You can give a comment on the parameter, what exactly does it do in this case?

Comment: The video duration is 11 seconds, when executed with the parameters `-vf select= ' gt(scene\, 0.4)', cropdetect-frames:v5` no response. I don't quite understand how to make it return the response both for a long video and for a short one. When this was done the process as soon as possible?